# Frobenius theorem: Notation in proof got me puzzled

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I was reading Serge Lang, Introduction to differentiable manifolds and in a proof concerning the chapter about the Frobenius theorem there was a condition that really makes no sense to me. I will give some background of the proof first and then state my problem.

Thus given a subbundle of $T(X)$ and a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the base space $X$.  By the definition of subbundle we can write locally a exact sequence,

$$ 0 \rightarrow U \times V \times \mathbf{E}  \xrightarrow{\tilde{f}} U \times V \times \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{F} $$
with the map

$$ f(x_0, y_0): \mathbf{E} \rightarrow \mathbf{E}\times \mathbf{F}$$

equal to the canonical embedding of $\mathbf{E}$. Now we state that $f$ can be written out in it two components, $f_1(x,y)$, $f_2(x,y)$ which map from $\mathbf{E}$ to $\mathbf{E}$,$\mathbf{F}$ resp. Taking a suitable VB-automorphism the first term may be assumed to equal the identity. Therefore we just write $f_2(x,y)$ as $f(x,y)$.

Consider a vector field $\xi$ over $U\times V$ and let $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ be its projections on $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ resp. Then $\xi$ lies in the image of $f$ if and only if

$$\xi_2(x,y) = f(x,y)\xi_1(x,y)$$

Then they state that they shall write,

$$ \xi(x,y) = (\xi_1(x,y), f(x,y)\xi_1(x,y)) $$

symbolically as,

$$ \xi = ( \xi_1, f\cdot\xi_1).$$

Okay so now I have introduced the notation, then they start the discussion about the bracket $[\xi, \eta]$. They state that $[\xi, \eta]$ lies in the image of $\tilde{f}$ if and only if

$$ Df(x,y) \cdot \xi(x,y) \cdot \eta_1(x,y) = Df(x,y) \cdot \eta(x,y) \cdot \xi_1(x,y). $$

My question now is how they obtain the above condition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "They" = "Serge Lang" ?!

Comment: Yeah indeed, I used they to reference to the book